# Proving the integral converges for all $p>1, q<1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

How can I prove that the integral 
$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p\ln^q(x)}
$$
converges when $p>1$ and $q<1$. I'm not sure where to start on this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Substitute $x=e^t$, it would become a familiar integral

EDIT: $dx=e^tdt$, thus, integral becomes $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(p-1)t}t^{-q}dt$$

Now substitute $(p-1)t=z$ which gives $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(p-1)t}t^{-q}dt=(p-1)^{q-1}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-z}z^{(1-q)-1}dz=(p-1)^{q-1}\Gamma(1-q)$$

Comment: Nice Avatar! Using modern Calculus makes me feel better. +1

Answer (score 3):

Another **hint** might be: Write the integral as $$\int_1^a\frac{dx}{x^p\ln^qx}+\int_a^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p\ln^qx},~~~a>1$$
I just remark some points about the first integral here. As $\ln x=\ln(1+(x-1))\sim(x-1)$ when $x\to 1^+$ so $\ln^qx\sim(x-1)^q$ when $x\to 1^+$ and then we have $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}(x-1)^q\times\frac{1}{x^p\ln^q x}\sim \lim_{x\to 1^+}(x-1)^q\times\frac{1}{x^p(x-1)^q}=1<\infty$$ so the comparison test says thee first part converges. Think about the second part or use @Avatar's way.

Comment: excellent, Babak! :+)